# Why is the set $U$ with $p(0)=c$ only a subspace of $P_3$ when $c\in \mathbb{R}=0$ ?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble grasping why the set $$ U_c = \{ p \in P_3\ |\ p(0) = c \}$$ with $c\in \mathbb{R}$ only counts as
a subspace of $P_3$ when $c=0$.
I've been told that it wouldn't be a valid subspace for $c\neq 0$ because:
$p_1(0)+p_2(0)=c_1+c_2=c_3\neq 0$. Consequently it wouldn't contain the zero vector with $c\neq 0$.

But why isn't it possible to simply multiply $p(0)$ with the scalar $\lambda=0$, such that:

$$\lambda p(0)=\lambda c= 0\cdot c= 0$$

Wouldn't that be a proof that $U_c$ **does** contain the zero vector with $c\neq 0$ because of the scalar multiplication with $0$?

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: The zero polynomial has constant term zero, so $\{p \in P_3 : p(0) = c\}$ only contains the zero polynomial if $c = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that $U_c$ is a subspace.

You are "proving" that the set contains the zero polynomial by using the "fact" that it is closed under scalar multiplication.

But (if I read your post correctly) you are saying that $U_c$ is closed under scalar multiplication because it is a subspace.

I hope it is clear that this is a circular argument - you are using the assumption that $U_c$ is a subspace in order to prove that it is a subspace.

Comment: Ok got it, I can't use a subspace property to show that a given set is a subspace. But is it as a result legitimate to say that a set of vectors does not contain the zero vector whenever there is a constant $c\neq 0$?

Comment: No.  It depends on exactly what the question is.  Every detail is important and questions which look fairly similar may have different answers.